# Problem on mysql INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

I am trying following query to show all of my user at user page...

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, u.email, u.active, u.admin,
u.team_id, t.name AS team_name, sum( s.score ) AS total_score
FROM users u
INNER JOIN teams t ON u.team_id = t.id
INNER JOIN stats s ON u.id = s.user_id
```

I have 4 users in my users table and i want to list all but if i use INNER JOIN, its returning only 1 row. Check data structure as following...

```
| id | game | user_id | rank | score | dnt |
+----+------+---------+-------+------+-----+
|  1 | test | 5       | 2    | 2200  | 
+--------+----------+----------+-----+-----+
|  2 | test | 3       | 1    | 2500  | 
+--------+----------+----------+-----+-----+
```

teams

```
| id | name  | dnt |
+----+-------+-----+
|  1 | team1 |     |
+----+-------+-----+
|  2 | team2 |     |
+----+-------+-----+
```

users

```
| id | username | email | team_id |
+----+----------+-------+---------+
|  1 | user1    |       | 1       |
+----+----------+-------+---------+
|  1 | user2    |       | 2       |
+----+----------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: Why do `user1` and `user2` both have `id` equal `1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `GROUP BY` in order to split score's sum over different users, further more if you use `LEFT JOIN` then you'll be sure to get a row for each user instance even if it has no rows in stats table (then, using `COALESCE` as [regilero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/550618/regilero) suggested, the sum will be `0`)

something like:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, u.email, u.active, u.admin,
u.team_id, t.name AS team_name, sum( COALESCE(s.score) ) AS total_score
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN teams t ON u.team_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN stats s ON u.id = s.user_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.username, u.email, u.active, u.admin,
u.team_id, t.name
```

this is not tested

Comment: hello, thanks for reply, its still returning 3 rows instead of 4. We have 4 users in users table and if we do simple `SELECT * from users` we get 4 users but using INNER JOIN gives 3 rows/users.

Comment: and if some users have no stats a left join on stats with a COALESCE in the sum could be used.

Comment: @Daniele actually `group by u.id` should be enough :)

Comment: hello i have updated INNER JOIN with LEFT JOIN, and its working, do you know why?

Comment: @seoppc because one user have no stats or team assigned.

Comment: does 'stats' contain all users id? (1,2,3,4) otherwise you need to use LEFT JOIN to 'join' even the rows which are not present in stats. If this is the case i'll update my answer

Comment: @Karolis: restricting the number of columns in GROUP BY expression is a mysql HACK on SQL and can lead to completly wrong queries (especially fro beginners), making the group by as they should be made in SQL is better, every SELECT column which is not an aggregate should be present in the Group by.

Comment: @regilero if this is the hack then what should be use to get our results?

Comment: @regilero Yeah I know this :) But I like this MySQL interpretation because such code is better readable and better understandable of what is **actually** being grouped. But sure, everything has its own downsides.

Comment: @seoppc: I was talking to Karolis about the group by with only the id field, the left join with coalesce is not a hack (it's SQL). Daniele Orler is right on the group by syntax, and now with the left join and coalesce you have your response. Except you may need to check your user id is unique, which is not the case in the provided example.